# How do I resolve a "module not found" error in cmd prompt

Tags: python, numpy, module

I try importing numpy from windows command prompt but got 'module not found' error

```
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy
```

However, I am able to import numpy successfully on jupiter notebook.
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to install it first using pip or conda

Answer (score 0):

From the information you gave , you probably have **multiple python installs** and one doesn't have numpy installed , if you have vscode you can check if you have multiple verisons with **ctrl+ shift + p** then typing **python interpreter**.